# Reload page with GET parameters

Tags: php, get, reload

I am developing a PHP page right now but I am stuck with a problem. How can I reload a webpage with get params using PHP? For example:

```
www.example.com/page.php
```

This is the page before.

```
www.example.com/page.php?view=list
```

This is the page after.

Comment: Do you mean *"redirect to"*?

Comment: You can't initiate a reload from serverside.

Comment: @symcbean you can, JS can query the server when it should reload the page.

Comment: @Kiril: exactly: JS can reload the page. Serverside can suggest when it should reload the page. But serverside cannot initiate a reload directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perform a redirect via the `header`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php